# Where to Place c3p0 configuration and getConnection method in rmi

Tags: java, rmi, c3p0

i m making a rmi based client server application.

At Server side, it consists of an java file running rmi(for binding registries)  and all the required interfaces implemeneted invoking other classes meant for various server based operation (which includes a connection with the database).

Now the doubt is

"*Where Shall I place the code for configuring **ComboPoolDataSource Instance** and the **getConnection()** method* so that the configuration can be done when i run the java rmi file and i can invoke **.getConnection()** from any other java file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At First...Create the code to initiate the connection in a class containing static methods or variables like this the following..

```
        private static ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        public static void MakePool()
        {
               try 
               {
                 cpds=new ComboPooledDataSource();
                 cpds.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                 cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/att_db");
                 cpds.setUser("root");
                 cpds.setPassword("dragon");
                 cpds.setMaxPoolSize(MaxPoolSize);
                 cpds.setMinPoolSize(MinPoolSize);
                 cpds.setAcquireIncrement(Accomodation);
             } 
             catch (PropertyVetoException ex) 
             {
                 //handle exception...not important.....
              }

}
public static Connection getConnection()
{
           return cpds.getConnection();
}
```

Once u r done Create another class meant for server operations....

and get the Connections from the Pool...

```
         try{

               con=DatabasePool.getConnection();
               // DatabasePool is the name of the Class made earlier....
               .
               .
               .
               .  // Server operations as u wanted.....
               .
               .
             }
             catch(SQL EXCEPTION HERE)
             {
                  .....
             }
             finally
             {     
               if(con!=null)
               {
                      con.close();      
               }
             }
```

Comment: @akp...wow...that's explains my question very well.......but what about JNDI...aren't they required...???

Comment: well...i don't know much about JNDI.....it's not required actually....doing this is enough.....

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in the startup class that does the bind, or in a singleton class.